# Improving the sum over dummy indexes

Tags: summation, tensors

I have the following `tensor`

```
tensor = {{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 
0}, {0, 0, 1/2, 0}, {0, 1/2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0,
1/2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -(1/2), 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0,
0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}}
```

I want to optimize the following sum

```
Sum[tensor[[i,j,k]]tensor[[i,j,k]],{i,1,4},{j,1,4},{k,1,4}]
```

by telling mathematica to Sum just over the non-vanishing elements of `tensor`.

Assume that I built the list of non-vanishing element positions of `tensor`, and call it `nonVanishPos = {{2,2,3},{2,3,2},{3,2,2},{2,3,3}}`

I want to perfom the Sum for `{i,j,k}` in `nonVanishPos`.

How to do it?

Answer (score 4):

It would be more efficient to just store as a `SparseArray[]` and use `Total[]`:

```
arr = SparseArray[{{2, 2, 3} -> 1/2, {2, 3, 2} -> 1/2,
                   {3, 2, 2} -> 1/2, {3, 3, 3} -> -1/2}, {4, 4, 4}];

Total[arr^2, 3]
   1
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I made a very simple example. Suppose that I have a rank-2 tensor `M`. I want to compute `M[i1,j1] M[i2,j2] M[i3,j3] arr[j1,j2,j3]` using the SparseArray. Any suggestion?

Comment: In that case, you might want to try figuring out how to express it with dot products, since *Mathematica* is more efficient in taking dot products than summing explicitly over an array's elements.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to figure out, but on the SparceArray there is not enough documentation on `Dot` usage with Sparce Arrays with different rank

Comment: @apt45 `SparseArray` is irrelevant here. Do you know how to express this as a dot product with normal arrays? It'll be the same for sparse arrays.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I don't know how to do it, this is the reason why I am writing these comments :)

Answer (score 3):

For the friends of Version 11.3:

```
nonVanishPos = Position[ tensor, x_?NumericQ /; Not@PossibleZeroQ[x] ]

MapAt[ Curry[Power][2], tensor, nonVanishPos ] // Curry[Total][Infinity]
```

> 1

Comment: Not really efficient, probably, but for the heck of it. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract) with [`TensorProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct):

```
TensorContract[
    TensorProduct[tensor,tensor],
    {{1,4},{2,5},{3,6}}
]
```

> 1

For the example in your earlier comment:

```
SeedRandom[2]
M = RandomInteger[1,{4,4}];

TensorContract[
    TensorProduct[M, M, M, tensor],
    {{2,7},{4,8},{6,9}}
]
```

> {{{-(1/2), 0, -(1/2), 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {-(1/2), 0, 0, 1/2}, {0, 0, 1/2, 1/
>      2}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{-(1/2), 0,
>       0, 1/2}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {1/2, 0, 1, 1/2}}, {{0, 0, 1/2, 1/
>      2}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {1/2, 0, 1, 1/2}, {1/2, 0, 1/2, 0}}}